# Leaflet: How to set the border to only show inside a polygon?

Tags: leaflet, border, polygon

I am wondering if it is possible with leaflet.js (current beta version) to only draw the border on the inside of the polygon (inline border).

For example: I have a square polygon with a 6px border. This would show 3px of the border on the inside of the polygon and the other 3px on the outside. Is there a way to only show the 3px on the inside?

A workaround is to reduce the size of the polygon and use the default border, but it would be nice to have an option without having to reduce the size of the polygon.

Does anyone know how to achieve this without reducing the size of the polygon?

Cheers

Comment: You might be interested in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38430112/is-there-any-way-to-create-two-color-border-in-leaflet-multipolygon-polygon/38440772#38440772

Comment: I have already read that post and am not that pleased with the result (the bug mentioned). If there is no other way, I would implement my own function rather then use the plugin mentioned in the post. But thanks for the comment!

Comment: Did you eventually find a better way?

Comment: No, I just used the reduced cell size as an aproximation. If you find a better way feel free to let me know. Unfortunately out of time constrains, I did not get into looking at this problem in much more detail.